# Loop json objects and add element together with value through user input

Tags: python, json

If I have a json file with multiple json objects such as following

```
{"created_at":"Sun Apr 16 02:00:14 +0000 2017","id":853427785339084800,"id_str":"853427785339084800"}

{"created_at":"Sun Apr 16 02:03:24 +0000 2017","id":853428582613475332,"id_str":"853428582613475332"}
```

I want to loop all the json objects add add new element together with value through user input in command line one by one. Is it possible because my format not in json array?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

tweets_data_path = 'data.json'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

pprint(tweets_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs fine, so I am assuming the question is on how to add user input as a new key-value pair for each json you load from the file. For python 2.7 use raw_input, for python 3 raw_input was renamed to [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

tweets_data_path = 'data.json'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweet["new_key"] = raw_input('provide input: ')
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

pprint(tweets_data)
```